# Transferring data regulary from MongoDB to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, apache-spark

We have a MongoDB that have heavy writes from a device. We want to regularly (maybe on schedule) read data from that MongoDB and transfer it to a SQL Server. Then that SQL server is where we would do all our analysis from.

What would be the best way to do the transfer and load from MongoDB to SQL Server?
Has anyone tried Apache Spark to do this?

Comment: if you need real time data then you may use changestream and have your custom application handle converting and saving mongodb document to SQL server... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a 3rd party utility called Studio 3T. It has functionality for  MongoDB to SQL Migration and a task can be created for it and can be scheduled. Also, the utility has more functionality other than migration which I find useful.

This utility was chosen due to limited budget. We just had to pay for ultimate license.